# JSON Highcharts to draw multiple lines

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm totally lost with Highcharts!. I have to draw a graph with multiple lines. I need a JSON output like this:

```
[{
    "name": "2",
    "data": 
    [1398333600000,1],[1398333600000,1],....
  },
  {
    "name": "16",
    "data": 
    [1398333600000,1],[1398333600000,1]...
  },
  {
    ....
    ....
  }
]
```

...but, I get only a malformed JSON response from PHP file. ¿Some altruistic soul can enlighten the way? thank you very much in advance. Sorry, I am a super-newbie :(

My BD table Mysql:

i can´t upload a image with table BD on post, sorry! ...i need at least 10 reputation!
...link...
http://i57.tinypic.com/2efj43n.jpg

The javascript code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'divStatsGrupo',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: titulo
                },
                tooltip: {
                enabled: false,        
                },
                xAxis: {    
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                hour: '%H:%M',
                labels: {
                     style: {
                     width: '200px','min-width': '100px'
                        },
                    useHTML : true
                }
                }   
                },

                yAxis: {
                categories: [ 'APAGADO', 'ACTIVO', 'ALARMA'],   
                title: {
                text: 'ESTADO'
                },
                min: 0
                },
               series : [{
                showInLegend: true,
                name : data.name,
                type : 'line',
                data: data.data 
                        }]
        });
});
```

And the PHP code:

```
require_once('Connections/conexion.php'); 
$sesionUser = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$sesionIdGrupo = $_GET['idGrupo'];
$sesionFechaActual = $_GET['fechaActual'];
///ARREGLO FECHA RECIBIDA PARA ADAPTARLA A FORMATO DE LA BD YY-MM-DD
$sesionFechaActualArreglo = date_format(new DateTime($sesionFechaActual),"Y-m-d");

mysql_select_db($database_conexion, $conexion); 
$query_RecordsetTabla = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE idUsuario = (SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios WHERE userName = '$sesionUser') AND idGrupo = '$sesionIdGrupo' AND fecha = '$sesionFechaActualArreglo'";
$RecordsetTabla = mysql_query($query_RecordsetTabla, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_RecordsetTabla = mysql_num_rows($RecordsetTabla); 

$arr = array();
while ($row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla))
{
$idDispositivo = $row_RecordsetTabla['idDispositivo'];
$fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
$hora = $row_RecordsetTabla['hora'];
$estado = $row_RecordsetTabla['estado']; 
$arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
$arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H:i");
$arregloHora2 = strtotime($arregloHora) * 1000;
$arr[] = array($arregloHora2, floatval($estado));
$arrDisp[] = array(floatval($idDispositivo));
}
$arr2 = array('data' => $arr, 'name' => $arrDisp);
echo json_encode($arr2);
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla);
```

I recieve this from PHP file...

```
{"data":[[1398330000000,1],[1398332700000,1],[1398331800000,1],[1398332700000,1]],"name":[[2],[2],[16],[16]]}
```

I think I have problems with arrays, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. I kept the code as similar to yours so you can see the minor differences.

```
$items = array();
while ($row_RecordsetTabla = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordsetTabla))
{
$idDispositivo = $row_RecordsetTabla['idDispositivo'];
$fecha = $row_RecordsetTabla['fecha'];
$hora = $row_RecordsetTabla['hora'];
$estado = $row_RecordsetTabla['estado']; 
$arregloFecha = date_format(new DateTime($fecha),"Y-m-d");
$arregloHora = date_format(new DateTime($hora),"H:i");
$arregloHora2 = strtotime($arregloHora) * 1000;
// changed $arr and $arrDisp to scalar
$arr = array($arregloHora2, floatval($estado));
$arrDisp = array(floatval($idDispositivo));
// name and data should be put as part of a single array
$items[]  = array ( 'data' => $arr , 'name' => $arrDisp );
}
// $arr2 = array('data' => $arr, 'name' => $arrDisp);
echo json_encode($items);
mysql_free_result($RecordsetTabla);
```

Please note I wasn't able to test it out, but if it does not work, let me know and I'll look at it further.

Comment: ....:( ...i can´t vote up your answer... ....i´m not have minimun range for vote... sorry

Comment: @xavi - that's not a problem - as long as you got the result you needed. You may be able to accept the answer though - if you'd like, try that out.

Comment: Ok! I've seen that "data" there is only one value for each "name". To draw the lines of Highcharts need the field "data" contains all values ​​with the same "name" ... (not if I explain too well ...)

Comment: What is the output you are getting? or rather, if you put some data into [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/) it might be easier to help you out.

Comment: Hello! your solution works perfectly ...! I think ... I have a design problem and approach. The return result is this: 
[{"data":[1398330000000,1],"name":[2]},{"data":[1398332700000,1],"name":[2]},{"data":[1398331800000,1],"name":[16]},{"data":[1398332700000,1],"name":[16]}] 

What is the expected response as I do the query in Mysql. 
But I need to draw the lines in Highcharts. Specifically are 2 lines (one for name 2 name and one for 16). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In your json_encode, I advice to set JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, then numbers will not be a strings.

Comment: I am grateful for the cooperation of the community. I'll try to fix it to see if it works.